# preg_split() Regex for Initials Lastname

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a name pattern looking like this:

F. O. O. Bar
F. Oobar
F. O. Obar

I'm currently trying to develop a regex that lets me split names in firstname, maybe initials and surname according to one of these.

```
foreach($authors as $author) {
    $arr = preg_split("/([a-zA-Z]. )+/", $author, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    //Do stuff with $arr
}
```

However, this also splits `Foo. Bar` (or to be exact `o.`). The problem is that I cannot limit it to lowercase only, as the data I have incoming are VERY inconsistent, so I cannot rely on this.

Comment: I just noticed you're using `preg_split` but you want to match? What *do* you really want?

Comment: @TimPietzcker match was the wrong choice of words, I do want to split actually. I have a list of names, and I need to split them in order to store them in a database that needs seperate entries for firstname(Initials) and surname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you only want to allow one letter before the dot? Use a word boundary to ensure this:

```
$arr = preg_split("/\b([a-zA-Z]\. )+/", $author, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Also, as wroniasty correctly noted, the dot needs escaping.

Answer (score 3):

The `.` has to be escaped.

```
$arr = preg_split("/([a-zA-Z]\. )+/", $author, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Thanks for that too, that caused an error I did not notice as well.